# best way to bind data from server to knockout

Tags: knockout.js

hello guys i am new in knockout.js and intrested in which is the best way to bind data from server to knockout. for example i want to bind categories variable and then use in select :

```
var myViewModel = function(){
    var self = this
    self.categories = []
    $.getJson("/ajax/categories", function(r){
        self.categories = r; 
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel ());

// in html
<select data-bind='options: categories'> </select>
```

Comment: you must assign using `()` convention i.e `self.categories(r)` and also try using optionsText in select .

Comment: thanks for response, categories is not function and it's not works. and is it the best way to bind data from server  such way or there is more cleaner way?

Comment: ok i changed categories to observableArray and it works, but if i do not want that categories to be observableArray and be just array? intrested in to find out the best way in such cases

Comment: oops sorry i missed that ! as `self.categories` is a plain js variable later on even if you assign value to it(under getJson) there is no way drop down is populated with your value as its not a observable Array . Plain variable doesn't update your view (it will only if you assign some default values on load not via xmlhttprequest )

Comment: As you are filling categories via getJson sever call its better to make it observableArray which is the best way & only way .

Comment: @supercool - man, sorry, I really read your comment after have posted the answer. if you want - post the answer and I will delete my one.

Comment: @TSV no problem mate helping is the agenda we done that . keep your answer as it is so OP can mark it correct . cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this
    self.categories = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJson("/ajax/categories", function(r) {
        self.categories(r); 
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

in html

```
<select data-bind='options: categories'> </select>
```

#### Update - Explanations

- One creates "myViewModel" in order to bind it to the markup.
- Categories collection is retreived from server via get request.
- Request is an async operation, thus categories array is empty when
  knockout bind it in applyBindings method.
- After some time request returns array of categories.
- And returned array is put into the observable array.
- Content of the observable array is changing and all subscribers get
  notified about it.
- Knockout binding engine is notified about array changes and rebuilds
  markup.

Comment: If some explanation were provided, this would be a suitable answer to be accepted (nature of data-binding, async, the 'why', basically supercool's comment).

Comment: @Tyblitz - no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The above explanation seems good, but little syntax error at 2 places:

1. $.getJson should be `$.getJSON` (in **caps**)

2. `$.getJSON` **closing parentheses** missing

All else is fine, can copy the corrected code from below:

```js
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this
    self.categories = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON("/ajax/categories", function(r) {
        self.categories(r);
    })
}
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```